# How to store input id value to a variable on another page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

say I have two pages. Page 1 (downloads data from the database) contains this code

```
//download_form
$id=(this variable should get the value of the input in page 2);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT  * FROM q1  WHERE q1.id ='$id'");
```

Page 2 (html form) contains this code.

```
<form method="post" action="../download_form.php" >
    <input type="submit" name="download" value="download" id="<?php echo 
     $row["id"]; ?>" class="btn-xs" />
</form>
```

What should i do so that when a user clicks download,download_form.php will get/post the value of the form id?

Answer (score 1):

Use a hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $row["id"] ?>" />
```

Then...

```
$id = $_POST['id'] ? intval($_POST['id']) : null; // for syntactic sugar see http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op
```

Also, your prepare is utterly useless if you are passing values to it directly anyway:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT  * FROM q1  WHERE q1.id ='$id'");
```

To

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT  * FROM q1  WHERE q1.id = ?");
$stmt->execute([$id]);
```

**Reading Material**

[input:hidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden)

[PDO Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: should i use this hidden input in page 2?(the page where the form is at?)

Comment: Yes, within the form.

Comment: @devpro yep. I'll change it to a ternary.

Comment: @Script47: u can also add a comment, IF YOU ARE USING PHP7 YOU CAN USE LIKE THAT... bla bla :p, well good answer.

Comment: @angelo if the answer helped, accept so it can be "closed".

Answer (score 0):

From your code you have to change the submit button code. You don't need to specify id in that i.e.

```
<input type="submit" name="download" value="download" id="<?php echo 
 $row["id"]; ?>" class="btn-xs" />
```

Here you shouldn't use id. Id is saved in another hidden field named "id".

```
<form method="post" action="../download_form.php" >
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $row["id"]; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="download" value="download" class="btn-xs" />
</form>
```

Now when you submit from Page 2 (press download button) "id" will be available on Page 1. You can extract it using this line.

```
$id = $_POST["id"];
```

then you will have information from page 2 to page 1.